# C# replace certain text within .plist / XML file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, plist

I am working on an application that will need to feed data into a `.plist` file. The places that need to be replaced have my custom text of something like `{Text-Placeholder}` or `{BackgroundColor-Placeholder}`.

Is there a way with C# where I can essentially just replace the instances of these? Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fileName = @"D:\X.plist";

// Load text from file
var text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

// Replace string
text = text.Replace("{Text-Placeholder}", "Some Text");
text = text.Replace("{BackgroundColor-Placeholder}", "Some Other Text");

// Save text to file
File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
```

In many cases, plist files are just XML files, so you can simply load and save them as any other text file. The only thing you have to pay attention to is Encoding.

`File.WriteAllText` will by default use UTF-8 encoding. So, when the plist file starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

then everything is alright. If the plist file uses a different encoding, you would have to specify that encoding as an additional parameter to `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: I'm aware you can do this for `.txt` files without any issues, I'm not sure it would work with `.plist` files?

Comment: @JoeScotto PList files are just XML files, so you can simply load and save them as any other text files.

Comment: Just tested it and it's working! Thank you very much.

Comment: @JoeScotto At some other places I have seen that plist files can also be in a binary format. However, I have never seen that in my iOS development projects.

Comment: For reference: [Trouble opening plist files in text editor](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101719/trouble-opening-plist-files-in-text-editor)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind if any issues arise but for right now it seems to be doing exactly what I want.